# Doing Anagram with case insensitive in python

Tags: python

Good day Guys! I'm a beginner at python. I wanted to make a program that does anagram with comparing two strings but I can't make a condition that also accepts both upper/and lowercase

```
str1 = input("Enter First String: ")
str2 = input("Enter Second String: ") 
#for white spaces
str1=''.join(str1.split())
str2=''.join(str2.split())

#to sort
#to check if they can be sorted equally, to check if the string is empty 
if (sorted(str1) == sorted(str2) and (len(str1)) and (len(str2))):
    
 print("Strings are anagram") 
else:
 print("Strings are not anagram")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.lower`, `.upper` or `.casefold` to ignore case.
(`.lower` converts everything to lowercase, `.upper` converts everything to uppercase and `.casefold` works just like `.lower` but it is more strict (e.g. the german letter `ß` equivalent to `ss`but because it's lowercase `.lower` doesn't do anything but `.casefold` will convert this to `ss`))

In your case you should add this in your condition:

```
if (sorted(str1.lower()) == sorted(str2.lower()) and (len(str1)) and (len(str2))):
```

full code:

```
str1 = input("Enter First String: ")
str2 = input("Enter Second String: ") 
#for white spaces
str1=''.join(str1.split())
str2=''.join(str2.split())

#to sort
#to check if they can be sorted equally, to check if the string is empty 
if (sorted(str1.lower()) == sorted(str2.lower()) and (len(str1)) and (len(str2))):
    
 print("Strings are anagram") 
else:
 print("Strings are not anagram")
```